# Using property grid to modify windows form properties

Tags: c#, .net

I an using a property grid to display the various properties of my custom form which the user can then modify. When I set the selected object to my form, it works, but it display all the properties of the form, Is it possible for me to define which form properties I want to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Browsable` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) to prevent properties from being shown. Unfortunately, you cannot change built-in types. If you inherit, and the property is not virtual, you cannot change it. Use aggregation instead if you want that.

EDIT: actually, while the above it true, you can overload this behavior by specifying your own Attribute and setting the [`BrowsableAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.browsableattributes.aspx) property of the `PropertyGrid` class that you inherit from. This way, you have all the freedom you want.

```
[Browsable(true)]
public bool GreatBrowsableProperty { get; set; }

[Browsable(false)]
public bool NonBrowsableProperty { get; set; }

[MyOwnBrowsable]
public bool BrowsablePropertyMyOwn { get; set; }
```

To learn more about creating and using attributes, [have a look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Could you please elaborate about the best way to do that?

Comment: @Serge: I just did, I was upgrading while you were typing your comment :)